# Program doesn't work if I declare class as const...rather than constexpr?

Tags: c++, class, constexpr

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>

class Debug {
public:
    constexpr Debug(bool h): hw(h){}
    constexpr bool any() { return hw; }
private:
    bool hw;
};

int main(){

    const Debug x(true);

    constexpr bool f = x.any();

}
```

This kicks up the error "the value of 'x' is not usable in a constant expression". If I replace

```
const Debug x(true);
```

with

```
constexpr Debug x(true);
```

Then everything runs fine. I was under the impression putting constexpr before an object definition was synonymous with "implicitly make this variable a const while verifying it is a constant expression variable". This would suggest to me that putting "const" instead of "constexpr" should be no different in the case of this program. In fact, if anything were to make an error, it should be declaring it as "constexpr", not as "const".

All aside though. I don't see how x is not a constant expression variable. The class Debug meets the criteria for a literal class type, x is declared as const and it uses a constexpr constructor with an initialisers that is a constant expressions.

Edit: This program kicks up the same error (admittedly this should've been my original program).

```
using namespace std;

class Debug {
public:
    constexpr Debug(bool h): hw(h){}
private:
    bool hw;
};

int main(){
    const Debug x(true);
    constexpr Debug f = x;
}
```

Comment: `x` is not `constexpr` so how do you expect to use it in a `constexpr` huh

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit, [This logic](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98449202527adb21)

Comment: @chris [`constexpr` no longer makes member functions `const`](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/constexpr-function-is-not-const/).

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit, Interesting, I wasn't aware that it was implicit in C++11. I was just trying to explain the OP's logic. "If it works for `int`, why not a class?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`constexpr` applied to a function means that the function's result is a constant expression if, and only if, all the function's inputs are constant expressions. In the case of a member function, the inputs are the arguments, and the object it's called on.

So `x.any()` is a constant expression only if `x` is `constexpr`. If it's merely `const`, then `x.any()` isn't a constant expression.

Comment: My issue came from thinking `constexpr` does not do anything different from `const` _except_ force the compiler to verify a variable is a constant expression. But `constexpr` actually forces compile-time initialisation whereas `const` does not. Thus, as you say, for variables I plan to use in constant expressions I need to make sure they are initialised with the `constexpr` qualifier.

Comment: And, crucially, since C++14 `constexpr` member functions are not implicitly `const`. Would make a good final sentence.